# Making several Request with Devtools

Tags: javascript, for-loop, request, console, google-chrome-devtools

I am trying to making dynamic consults through "for loop" on a website, once the information is in the text box, I use Document.getElementById ("link").Click() to making the query and get the desired information from what I enter in the text box dynamically.

Something like that:

```
var id = ["13454" , "134547", "1348878"];
for(i=0;i<id.length;i++){
document.getElementById("ParameterBox").value = id[i];
document.getElementById("consult").click();
var result = document.getElementById("result").value;
console.log(result);
}
```

the problem is then when I run the code, I only get a response from the last element of the "for loop".
It's like document.getElementById("consult").click() did not execute for all the elements of the array.

Any suggestion?

Comment: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: What person above said... Please share you code on stackoverflow, not images of code.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I already edited.